# Javascript using external function

Tags: javascript

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzVXz9FRg0DWV3R0WUR2cTd5U00/edit

I need to call the function from the javascript linked above in my userscript. My code where I need the function looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.color1').colorPicker();
});
```

I tried:

```
var decolorpicker = '<script type="text/javascript" scr=”www.drive.google.com/file/d/0BzVXz9FRg0DWV3R0WUR2cTd5U00/edit?usp=sharing”></script>'
$("script[src*='merged/game']").after(decolorpicker);
```

And then:

```
window.colorPicker();
```

Which gives the error:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'window.colorPicker' is not a function
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- declare your markup first -->
  <div class="color1"></div>

<!-- then include your functions ( jquery also ) -->
<script src="www.drive.google.com/file/d/0BzVXz9FRg0DWV3R0WUR2cTd5U00/edit?usp=sharing"></script>

<!-- then you can apply  -->
<script>
   $('.color1').colorPicker();
</script>
```

UPDATE:

**Make sure that the linked JS is a javascript file.**
When I visit www.drive.google.com/file/d/0BzVXz9FRg0DWV3R0WUR2cTd5U00/edit?usp=sharing it takes me to a google docs file. This is NOT a javascript file.

Comment: I notice that, when I add the JS file, the link changes to: <script type="text/javascript" scr="�http://yourjavascript.com/1694801572/colorpickernew.js�"/>. Those two weird icons, why are they there? :x

Comment: Just something I copied from your example, they should be simple quotes, what are you editing in ? Just about to make an update -

Comment: I'm using Komodo Edit 8.0. And it's not your code I'm using (yet), but when I inspected the head of the page, i noticed I get those two weird symbols added to the src, and when I check resources, the script isn't found. So I think I'm doing something wrong when adding the source javascript

Comment: Kk, my bad, I copied those ""'s but they were in a different coding. Thx

Comment: yes, looks like the file from the google docs is not downloading as a text only javascript file and is a webpage. Glad you got sorted